# Tokenize a String in Java

Tags: java, string, tokenize

I have a String

```
a-b-c
```

Then I want to tokenize the string by character '-', the result would be

```
[a, b, c]
```

But then I have a String

```
a---c
```

The result should be

```
[a, -, c]
```

Is there already a tokenizer in Java which can do this?

Comment: Yes! There is a string tokenier http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html

Comment: StringTokenizer is a legacy class (for several versions of Java now) and should not be used anymore.
use regex or String's split method.

Comment: Another possible result would be `[a--, c]`. Is it always one character values separated by hyphens? We need some rule to avoid ambiguous results.

Comment: If the overall structure of your string is fixed, you really should got with an appropriate [regular expression](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html).

Comment: String.split takes a regex as an argument. Did you try myString.split("-+") ?

Comment: @matthias - you need a pattern for using REGEX.. I see no pattern

Comment: @TheLostMind The OP hasn't said he wants to use regex. He doesn't need to provide a pattern in his question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a solution using only regexps to give you the needed result for your test data:

```
\b-|-\b
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/8p4q_PTnSYe_V4L9)

The word boundary (`\b`) possibilities are often underestimated but can simplify many regexps dramatically.

With the provided regexp you can now use Javas `split` method. So the little testclass could look like:

```
public class SimpleRegExp {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String regexp = "\\b-|-\\b";
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString("a-b-c".split(regexp)));
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString("a---c".split(regexp)));
    }
}
```

and prints this result:

```
[a, b, c]
[a, -, c]
```

Answer (score 0):

This (first try) appears to handle your samples as requested.

```
String rex = "(?<=-)-(?=\\w)|(?<=\\w)-(?=-)|(?<=\\w)-(?=\\w)";
String[] t1 = s1.split( rex );
```

Is a \w a correct assumption in contrast to '-'? Otherwise this should be changed.

Also, I think it can be condensed somewhat.

Comment: "a----c" is split into a, --, b which may or may not be what you want.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume your delimiter is always one hyphen, and that `---` would split to `[-,-]`. And that `----` would either be invalid or split to `[-,-]`. In which case, the following would work for you:

```
private static List<String> tokenize(String input, char delimeter) {
    List<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

    for (char c : input.toCharArray()) {
        if (builder.length() == 0) {
            builder.append(c);
        } else if (c == delimeter) {
            result.add(builder.toString());
            builder.setLength(0);
        } else {
            builder.append(c);
        }
    }

    if (builder.length() > 0) {
        result.add(builder.toString());
    }

    return result;
}
```

Test code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String s1 = "a-b-c";
    String s2 = "a---c";

    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(tokenize(s1, '-').toArray()));
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(tokenize(s2, '-').toArray()));
}
```

Prints:

```
[a, b, c]
[a, -, c]
```